# How input a (rating) value in Excel cell by clicking on a (5-stars-like) object

Tags: excel, forms, click, controls

For the purpose of building an Excel survey form, I want to create an easy rating entry system that would set values in cells based on a single click on a rating object (form control). With this click on say a 5-stars object it would return a value (from 1 to 5) based on which star is clicked (0 if not clicked), value that would be stored in a linked cell. The form should have such 5-stars objects next to a list of questions.

Using Excel built-in controls would limit option to the spin button, which isn't as convenient.
I haven't found any other suitable controls, nor ActiveX (which would make it more difficult to share the sheet).

Thanks for your insights on how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to digress from your wish to have stars as buttons, the excel form controls seem to be more than able of what you are looking for. You could use Option Buttons to achieve something like this: [image]

A detailed guide on how to use these Buttons can be found [here](https://trumpexcel.com/insert-use-radio-button-in-excel/)

Comment: Thx for the quick feedback and proposed solution. That is a workaround indeed, but at a price of more complication. I might reconsider other built-in control variants (like spin button) before going down this route.